# The chat/user links on the meta sidebar are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, sidebar

They lead to http://chat.meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/rooms/# rather than http://chat.gaming.stackexchange.com/rooms/#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<waves hand>

no they're not.

Comment: No, they are not.